# Question about firebse firestore pricing (about reads)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a collection with 1000 documents and I want to query the document inside that collection that has the field, `'name'` set to 'user01'. Does that finding count as 1000 reads ? If so is there a more cost effective way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are charged for the number of documents returned by your query. If you query documents `where("name", "==", "user01)"` and there are 45 documents out of those 1000 documents that match this, then you'll be charged 45 reads.